# SFINAE: function templates optimation

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++14, sfinae

I would like iterate over an tuple in some way with member function templates (for later create a new type of tuple from the given template type `T`).

However, the break condition (function) is not used so I get this error:

> invalid use of incomplete type: 'class std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple<> >'

The problem seems to be, that even though `N == size` of the tuple, `std::tuple_element_t` is evaluated for `N != size` and not handled as SFINAE.

Both examples showing different not working solutions. What do I wrong?

*Note: The function for evaluated with `is_same` is omitted to minimize the example.*

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename...Ts>
struct A
{
  using tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
  static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);

  template<typename T, std::size_t N = 0, typename std::enable_if_t<N == size>* = nullptr>
  int get()
  {
    return 0;
  }

  template<typename T, std::size_t N = 0, typename std::enable_if_t<N != size && !std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple>>::value>* = nullptr>
  int get()
  {
    return get<T, N + 1>() - 1;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A<int, float, double, float, float> a;

  return a.get<char>();
}
```

[Live Example 1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B1z+-O3+-Wall+-ftemplate-backtrace-limit%3D0',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4AuBPADgg%2BmgJwEMQ0BnAPgChRJZFU0YsoFqq0EBbFoz9bAjBEuCAHQSAKpSpIkZQjAhokAQVlIA3hrkwy4AOZImLZAF55aOAC5rJ1imkSxFANw7LfEBCQQA9mAKCAAeWASWNtb6AF54KjHm8iCxfgBmzgAU0gCU7h6cPFB8CAI4wqJIkgA0EbYJ%2BEgAckgWAAw1mGUiyAqRQkQARqy4IKn4KM1mFgkUAFQtSGAwUFBYhNRym0jgKgYIaBnZHtpbcgT7MARgSK3uWwC%2BVPncvPyd/RXVtVHJcU0L7WMgnKPSstn6Qzwo3GzQAhNNfkgAGRIpCw3q2EBkXBkbqOGoYuzMYYIViiMBoGEdYlsCi2ABuRFgbHmFiWKzWBA2px2SD2ByOWxOp3OTCufP2%2BP%2BAGokABGCiHJAAWnld02jzk9zyvK4JDAhyowtUKB2NVSUD8fBqcD8MEh5st1qQFqtaAoSCIeTOF3FRDE/JQEAAFkQuYd3PcgAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename...Ts>
struct A
{
  using tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
  static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);

  template<typename T, std::size_t N = 0>
  std::enable_if_t<N == size, int> get()
  {
    return 0;
  }

  template<typename T, std::size_t N = 0>
  std::enable_if_t<N != size && !std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple>>::value, int> get()
  {
    return get<T, N + 1>() - 1;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A<int, float, double, float, float> a;

  return a.get<char>();
}
```

[Live Example 2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B1z+-O3+-Wall+-ftemplate-backtrace-limit%3D0',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4AuBPADgg%2BmgJwEMQ0BnAPgChRJZFU0YsoFqq0EBbFoz9bAjBEuCAHQSAKpSpIkZQjAhokAQVlIA3hrkwy4AOZImLZAF55aOAC5rJ1imkSxFANw7LfEBCQQA9mAKCAAeWASWNtb6AF54KjHm8iCxfgBmzgAU0gCU7h6cPFB8CAI4wqJIkgA0EbYJ%2BEgAckgWAAzUcp211kJEAEasuCCp%2BCjNZhYJNeBoFEgGCGgZ2R5y2l1dBIswBGBIre4bSAC%2BVPncvPyYZSLI1d31KuP7HRsKkb0DeMOjzQCEk2SyAAZMCkH93rYQGRcGRbo4apC7MxBghWKIwGhfjV7GwKLYAG5EWAIaaYuYLJYrI7rI5ILZMXbzRYIppIADUSAAjBRlkgALTcw4bU5yY55GZILgkMDLKi01QoGY1VJQPx8GpwPwwL4qtUapCq9WzJBEPJyBk7PZEMSUlAQAAWRAIvNyVGOQAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

One workaround would be to use a third function to evaluate until sizeof tuple - 2 and than evaluate sizeof tuple - 1, but Is this really necessary?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename...Ts>
  struct A
  {
    using tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);

    template<typename T, std::size_t N = 0, typename std::enable_if_t<(N == size - 1) && std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple>>::value>* = nullptr>
      int get()
    {
      return 1;
    }

    template<typename T, std::size_t N = 0, typename std::enable_if_t<(N == size - 1) && !std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple>>::value>* = nullptr>
      int get()
    {
      return 2;
    }

    template<typename T, std::size_t N = 0, typename std::enable_if_t<(N < size - 1) && !std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple>>::value>* = nullptr>
      int get()
    {
      return get<T, N + 1>() - 1;
    }
  };

int main()
{
  A<int, float, double, float, float> a;

  return a.get<char>();
}
```

[Live Example 3](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B1z+-O3+-Wall+-ftemplate-backtrace-limit%3D0',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4AuBPADgg%2BmgJwEMQ0BnAPgChRJZFU0YsoFqq0EBbFoz9bAjBEuCAHQSAKpSpIkZQjAhokAQVlIA3hrkwy4AOZImLZAF55aOAC5rJ1imkSxFANw7LfEBCQQA9mAKCAAeWASWNtb6AF54KjHm8iCxfgBmzgAU0gCU7h6cPFB8CAI4wqJIkgA0EbYJ%2BEgAckgWAAw1mGUiyAqRQkQARqy4IKn4KBnNZhYJSAC0SACM2UgAZKu11iBkuGTdjjW9tvZ4CKyiYGjjjR3MrBQUtgBuRLBsAFQtSGAwUFBYhGocmBSHAKgMCDQGWyHm0ILkBEhMAIYCW7hBAF8PPluLx%2BJ1%2BhVqpt6iopkh2sZBOUelZbP0hnhRuNJi0ZslkAtlmsNgBCI5bHZ7UQHTYnXBnbhCK5oFA3Yx3NiPawvN4UT4WH5/AEEIHwsFICFQmEguHwxFMFFIABM6OBWJxhWKpUJyGJAtJTS%2BlIJNM2DOGzNlrJQSVi8yWK3WSH5dMFu327rj4slFxlctupgez1eMA%2BXy1/0BHjkBqN0NhJaQFuRqKNouaAGolhRoRHFna5Fiu3kDVwSGAK2bVCgwTVUlA/HwanA/DBGePJ9OkBOp2gKEgiHkEUirUQxPWIAALIi66HuDFAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

Comment: The last index is `size-1`, not `size`, so `N` should be compared with value `size-1`

Comment: I know, so the last function (termination) should be one index over the size of elements (that is because N != size). If I would have 4 functions with different behaviors for N < size - 1, I would also need 4 functions for N == size -1. I want to compensate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39499283/4987285) answer the OP said:

> It does solve the problem but not for automatic type return type deduction based on which function is used (returning int was just an example). I should have been clearer on this.

It follows a minimal, working example that probably solves the problem also for that.
It's far easier to reason in terms of inheritance and tag dispatching in this case, so as to reduce the boilerplate due to sfinae. Moreover, one can use specializations to introduce specific behaviors for specific types if needed.
The final case, the one for the type that is not part of the types list, is easily handled in a dedicated function as well.

It follows the code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename>
struct tag {};

template<typename...>
struct B;

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct B<T, Ts...>: B<Ts...> {
    using B<Ts...>::get;

    auto get(tag<T>) {
        return T{};
    }
};

template<>
struct B<> {
    template<typename T>
    auto get(tag<T>) {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

template<typename...Ts>
struct A: private B<Ts...>
{
    template<typename T>
    auto get() {
        return B<Ts...>::get(tag<T>{});
    }
};

int main()
{
  A<int, float, double, float, float> a;
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a.get<char>()), std::nullptr_t>::value, "!");
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a.get<float>()), float>::value, "!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @PiotrSkotnicki in the comments to the question, here is your second example once fixed:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename...Ts>
struct A
{
  using tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;
  static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);

  template<typename T, std::size_t N = 0>
  std::enable_if_t<N == size-1, int>
  get()
  {
    return std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple>>::value ? N : 0;
  }

  template<typename T, std::size_t N = 0>
  std::enable_if_t<N != size-1 && !std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple>>::value, int>
  get()
  {
    return get<T, N + 1>() - 1;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A<int, float, double, float, float> a;
  return a.get<char>();
}
```

What was the problem?
Consider the following line:

```
std::enable_if_t<N != size && !std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple>>::value, int> get()
```

In this case, `N` was substituted in order to evaluate the condition of the `enable_if`, even when `N == size` (substitution is mandatory to find that `N == size` indeed).
Thus, the `tuple_element_t` (let me say) issued an out of range and that's why you got the compilation error.

I've simply updated your code to avoid reaching `size` while iterating over `N`. It was a matter of using `size-1` as a value on which to switch between functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does solve the problem but not for automatic type return type deduction based on which function is used (returning int was just an example). I should have been clearer on this. However, you are right, the problem is the compile time error of the evaluation of the tuple_element.

Comment: @Viatorus I've added [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39506313/4987285) that probably solves your problem. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an additional struct that, with partial specialization, can avoid the use of `std::tuple_element_t` ?

I mean, something like

```
  template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  struct checkType
   { constexpr static bool value
      = std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<N, tuple>>::value; };

  template <typename T>
  struct checkType<T, size>
   { constexpr static bool value = false; };

  template <typename, std::size_t N = 0>
  std::enable_if_t<N == size, int> get ()
   { return 0; }

  template <typename T, std::size_t N = 0>
  std::enable_if_t<(N < size) && ! checkType<T, N>::value, int> get()
   { return get<T, N + 1>() - 1; }
```